# Yet another LEFT OUTER JOIN fail in SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I'm wondering if someone might be able to troubleshoot my query. I have a simple table that has project savings per month. There are always 12 consecutive months worth or savings, but the first month can vary (e.g.: start from January for 12 months, start from March for 12 months, etc).

I need a report that gets me all savings (by month) for a given year. This means that for some project savings, if the start month is not January, then some of that project savings will fall in a different report year.

So I need a query that will return all months for the current report year, and have zero haves for where a project doesn't have saving values for that month.

I have some projects starting in July, and I'm only getting back those 6 months with their value. That is, the left join back to the date WITH is not outer joining properly. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

See code below:

```
DECLARE @MonthEndSnapshot SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT @MonthEndSnapshot =  getdate()

DECLARE @StartDate SMALLDATETIME, @EndDate SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT @StartDate = FORMAT(@MonthEndSnapshot, 'yyyy') + '0101', @EndDate = FORMAT(@MonthEndSnapshot, 'yyyy') + '1231';

;WITH d(d) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0))
    FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 
             (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
             n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
         FROM 
             sys.all_objects 
         ORDER BY [object_id]) AS n
)
select  
    left(datename(month, d.d), 3) as xAxisValueMon,
    datepart(mm, d.d) as xAxisValue,
    a.ProjectId as ProjectId, 
    ISNULL(SUM(a.Saving), 0) as yAxisValue
from 
    d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         mes.ProjectId, mes.Saving, mes.SavingMonth
     FROM 
         dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving() mes) AS a ON d.d = a.SavingMonth
group by 
    a.ProjectId,  datename(month, d.d), datepart(mm, d.d)
order by   
    a.ProjectId, datepart(mm, d.d)
```

The WITH d(d) part works, and returns 12 month dates (1st month from Jan to Dec).

I also tried the following structure as the query:

```
;WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)
select  left(datename(month, d.d), 3) as xAxisValueMon,
    datepart(mm, d.d) as xAxisValue,
    mes.ProjectId as ProjectId, 
    ISNULL(SUM(mes.Saving), 0) as yAxisValue
from d LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving() mes 
    ON d.d = mes.SavingMonth
group by mes.ProjectId,  datename(month, d.d), datepart(mm, d.d)
order by   mes.ProjectId, datepart(mm, d.d)
```

But same results. The `MonthEndSaving` table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MonthEndSaving]
(
    [MonthEndSavingId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MonthEndSnapshot] [datetime] NOT NULL,   
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SavingMonth] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Saving] [money] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MonthEndSavingId)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE MonthEndSaving
    ADD CONSTRAINT [ProjectMonthEndSaving] 
    FOREIGN KEY (ProjectId) REFERENCES [dbo].[Project](ProjectId) 
GO
```

Comment: What values does `mes.SavingMonth` bring ??

Comment: The projectID will only be shown for months in which that project has a `SavingMonth` value that matches a month in your `d` set. If you want each project ID to show up you will have to join them unconditionally. Your condition needs to be in a `CASE` statement inside of your `SUM` if I'm understanding correctly (e.g. `ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN mes.SavingMonth = MONTH(d.d) THEN mes.Saving ELSE 0 END),0)`).

Comment: Focusing on just one ProjectId (that starts Saving from July onward), you expect to get 12 records: one for Jan, one for Feb, one for March, etc... and you expect those first 6 records to have a zero amount and the 7th and further on to have the relevant amounts from the table-function. Right? And the issue is that you only get 6 records : one for July, one for August, one for September etc.. each with their respective amounts. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't seem to work.  So SavingMonth is a date, so I fixed you line of code to:

Comment: For some reason us noobs can't edit ... here's what that previous comment was saying:

Thanks for the reply but that doesn't seem to work.  So SavingMonth is a date, so I fixed you line of code to:

`ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(mes.SavingMonth) = MONTH(d.d) THEN mes.Saving ELSE 0 END),0) as yAxisValue`

But it still doesn't LEFT JOIN properly, and I am only getting 6 rows for a project with savings from Jul-2016 to Jun-2017.

Comment: The issue is that you need to effectively have three tables: the Months (taken care of with your cte), the Projects (not present), and the Project/Month savings (which you have). Derive a third SELECT to get the projects you need, CROSS JOIN those to your Months, and LEFT JOIN the savings, with an ISNULL(savings, 0.00) for output purposes.

Comment: @deroby yes that exactly correct

Comment: You could `CROSS JOIN` your results instead, but be careful as this will result in 12 records for every record available in your `sf_SnapShotMonthEndSaving()` dataset. Or you could `CROSS JOIN` to `(SELECT ProjectID, SUM(Saving), SavingMonth FROM sf_SnapShot.... GROUP BY ProjectID, SavingMonth) mes`

Comment: @LaughingVergil ... I don't need to join to the Project table (because the ProjectId is like a Tax File Number / Social Security Number ... it's fine in that format).  Either way, this query should still LEFT JOIN correctly without a JOIN to a project table (as per deroby's description).

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or then write them in all lowercase (select, from) - but pick **one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix and match!

Comment: @marc_s ... ah you must be the **style police**!  Yeah, I do stick to one style, but in this case I passed the code to someone who decided not to.  At present my priority is to get it working than worry about preening it.  But thank you for that **valuable input**.

Comment: @AidenDipple: **no**; I'm no **police** - I don't care nor do I tell you *which* style to use - that's entirely up to you. I'm just saying you should pick **one** and then **STICK TO IT** - that'll make your own developer life easier down the road, too!

Comment: @marc_s ah, so it's not the _which_ but the _how_ that you're **POLICING**! Psst - I think people are laughing at us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you need:

```
DECLARE @MonthEndSnapshot SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT @MonthEndSnapshot =  getdate()



DECLARE @StartDate SMALLDATETIME, @EndDate SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT @StartDate = FORMAT(@MonthEndSnapshot, 'yyyy') + '0101', @EndDate = FORMAT(@MonthEndSnapshot, 'yyyy') + '1231';

;WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)
select  left(datename(month, d.d), 3) as xAxisValueMon,
    datepart(mm, d.d) as xAxisValue,
    prj.ProjectId as ProjectId, 
    ISNULL(SUM(a.Saving), 0) as yAxisValue
from d 
CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT mes.ProjectId
        FROM dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving() mes
    ) as prj
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT mes.ProjectId, mes.Saving, mes.SavingMonth
        FROM dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving() mes 
    ) as a
    ON d.d = a.SavingMonth
    AND prj.ProjectID = a.ProjectID
group by prj.ProjectId,  datename(month, d.d), datepart(mm, d.d)
order by prj.ProjectId,  datepart(mm, d.d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dang, Laughing Vergil seems to be a faster typist =)
Anyway, the idea is pretty much the same. Your 'error' was that you join each month to ALL the projects in `dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving()`. If one fits, it gets returned for that one only, if two fit, it will show those two etc... but it will NOT repeat for EVERY project. This should.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '1 jan 2016',
        @EndDate datetime = '1 dec 2016'

;WITH d(FirstDayOfMonth) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
),
RelevantProjects AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId
     FROM dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving() mes
    WHERE mes.SavingMonth BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate -- you could also join to d but I think this is faster
),
ProjectsAndDates AS
(
    SELECT ProjectID,
           FirstDayOfMonth
      FROM d
     CROSS JOIN RelevantProjects
)
select  left(datename(month, d.FirstDayOfMonth), 3) as xAxisValueMon,
        datepart(mm, d.FirstDayOfMonth) as xAxisValue,
        d.ProjectId as ProjectId, 
        ISNULL(SUM(mes.Saving), 0) as yAxisValue
   from ProjectsAndDates d 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [MonthEndSaving] mes  -- dbo.sf_SnapshotMonthEndSaving() mes 
                 ON mes.SavingMonth = d.FirstDayOfMonth
                AND mes.Project_id  = d.ProjectID
   group by d.ProjectId, datename(month, d.FirstDayOfMonth), datepart(mm, d.FirstDayOfMonth)
   order by d.ProjectId, datepart(mm, d.FirstDayOfMonth)
```

Comment: Awesome!!  Thanks for that @deroby and @LaughingVergil!  In reality I do still have to join it to a Project table to get ProjectTypeId instead of just ProjectId.  But you've helped me sort out the problem with the JOIN.  Let's see how I can stuff it up from here!  ;p